# how to display specific results from the dropdown in models.py in django

Tags: python, django

I want to display only employees which emp_type is 'Doctor'?

** Here is Models.py **

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    emp_type_choices = [
        ('Nurse', 'Nurse'),
        ('Doctor', 'Doctor'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    ]
    emp_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, choices=emp_type_choices, default='Nurse')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ticket(models.Model):
    patient = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

**This is my Forms.py**

```
class TicketModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['doctor', 'status']
        widgets = {
            'doctor': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Doctor Name'}),        
        }
```

**This is my Views.py**

```
@login_required
def TicketToGenerateView(request, pk):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=pk)

    form = TicketModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():    
        obj.save()
        return redirect('/dashboard/ticket')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'ticket': ticket,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/ticket.html', context)
```

**This is my Template**

```
 <form action="." method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}.
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ field }}
                {% if field.errors %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p class="text-danger">{{ error|escape }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group float-right">         
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value=" {{ valueBtn }} "> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

In the template, I'm displaying all registered employees as a dropdown list, but I would like to display only employees which their emp_type is 'Doctor'.

Also the Admin site I would like to see the only emp_type which are 'Doctor'.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Ahmad Ebrahim. Welcome to SO. Could you please add your views.py and template to the question?

Comment: I added. please, it's urgent to solve that problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# You have to use filter for your query

emp_doctor = Employee.objects.filter(emp_type='Doctor')

print(emp_doctor)
```